# Adding value to 2d numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

Having trouble manipulating a 2D numpy array (below). I'm using np.where to add a value if the given condition is met, but doesn't seem to be working. Is this simply not possible or am I making a simple mistake?

```
a = ['circle','square']
b=['north','south']
c=['red','blue']
d=['long','short']
x = []
for shape in a:
  for direction in b:
    for color in c:
      for length in d:
        x.append([shape, direction, color, length, 0])
x = np.array(x)

# conditional add - if condition is met, add 1 to numeric index, else assign value of 2
x[:,4] = np.where((x[:,0]=='circle') & (x[:,1]=='south'), x[:,4]+1, 2)
```

Comment: the num in numpy stands numerical. Why are you using numpy if not dealing with numbers?

Comment: And what exactly  "is not working" [ask] and [mre]

Comment: seems you'd be better off using `itertools.product` to generate `x` rather than nested `for` loops, then just manipulate it as a native list?

Comment: for my specific use case, I was initially using a dictionary, however the number of nested layers increased to a point where it became very inefficient to access and update, so instead I decided to test using an array, not against using a nested list either. I'm not against alternative solutions, all I'm trying to do is construct some mechanism that can store values that i can quickly access and update based on conditional filtering

Comment: Then perhaps you could create a purely numerical array, using the indexes of the values in the respective lists instead of the values themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use indices instead of labels when creating your numpy array; that way it would be a numerical array and your last statement would work:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

parameters = [
    ['circle', 'square'],
    ['north', 'south'],
    ['red', 'blue'],
    ['long', 'short'],
    ]

x = np.array(list(product(*map(lambda my_list: range(len(my_list)), parameters), [0])))

x[:,4] = np.where((x[:,0]==0) & (x[:,1]==1), x[:,4]+1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have just complained about the "not working" statement, and wait for you to provide real information about the problem.  But lets test your code.

First look at `x`

```
In [290]: x
Out[290]: 
array([['circle', 'north', 'red', 'long', '0'],
       ['circle', 'north', 'red', 'short', '0'],
       ['circle', 'north', 'blue', 'long', '0'],
       ['circle', 'north', 'blue', 'short', '0'],
       ['circle', 'south', 'red', 'long', '0'],
       ['circle', 'south', 'red', 'short', '0'],
         ...
       ['square', 'south', 'blue', 'short', '0']], dtype='<U11')

In [291]: x.shape
Out[291]: (16, 5)
```

It's a 2d array, with 5 columns - your 4 label ones, plus the "0" last.  Note that is a string.

And the `where` complains about that:

```
In [292]: np.where((x[:,0]=='circle') & (x[:,1]=='south'), x[:,4]+1, 2)
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U11'), dtype('int32')) -> None
   
In [293]: x[:,4]
Out[293]: 
array(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
       '0', '0', '0'], dtype='<U11')
```

An array filled with strings will have string values in all columns.

We can do the math by first converting the strings to integers:

```
In [295]: np.where((x[:,0]=='circle') & (x[:,1]=='south'), x[:,4].astype(int)+1, 2)
Out[295]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

But when those numbers are assigned  back to the array, they will be converted to strings:

```
In [296]: x[:,4] = np.where((x[:,0]=='circle') & (x[:,1]=='south'), x[:,4].astype(int)+1, 2)    
In [297]: x[:,4]
Out[297]: 
array(['2', '2', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
       '2', '2', '2'], dtype='<U11')
```

As long as you keep that in mind, it shouldn't be a problem in further work.

### pandas

With `pandas` it's easy to make a frame with mixed  dtypes.  From the list of lists (not the array):

```
In [301]: a = ['circle','square']
     ...: b=['north','south']
     ...: c=['red','blue']
     ...: d=['long','short']
     ...: x = []
     ...: for shape in a:
     ...:   for direction in b:
     ...:     for color in c:
     ...:       for length in d:
     ...:         x.append([shape, direction, color, length, 0])
     ...:         

In [302]: x
Out[302]: 
[['circle', 'north', 'red', 'long', 0],
 ['circle', 'north', 'red', 'short', 0],
 ['circle', 'north', 'blue', 'long', 0],
 ...
 ['square', 'south', 'blue', 'short', 0]]

In [303]: df=pd.DataFrame(x)

In [304]: df
Out[304]: 
         0      1     2      3  4
0   circle  north   red   long  0
1   circle  north   red  short  0
2   circle  north  blue   long  0
...
15  square  south  blue  short  0

In [305]: df.dtypes
Out[305]: 
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
4     int64
dtype: object
```

The `where` can now work directly with the 4th numeric column:

```
In [307]: np.where((df[0]=='circle') & (df[1]=='south'), df[4]+1, 2)
Out[307]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)

In [308]: df[4]=np.where((df[0]=='circle') & (df[1]=='south'), df[4]+1, 2)

In [309]: df
Out[309]: 
         0      1     2      3  4
0   circle  north   red   long  2
1   circle  north   red  short  2
2   circle  north  blue   long  2
 ....
```

`numpy` also allows mixed dtypes in a structured array, but if you can use `pandas` it's probably simpler.